# Render Text of Mandrill Template with API

Tags: mandrill

Is there a way to get the rendered Text and not just HTML from the Mandrill API? I would like to be able to test that merging produces the correct output in text version of emails. /templates/render.json doesn't look like it returns 'text'.

Comment: did you tried ? **var api = new MandrillApi(ApiKey);

          
            var resultRender = api.Render(templateExample, templateContent, null);** C# code MandrillApi